# Typo3 6.2 Module: How to add an action to an existing module

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I need your help!

**Goal:**
A Typo3 6.2 module should be extended with a button to delete all user data inserted. By default it is only possible to delete data one-by-one.

**Conditions:**
no changes in the core data of the original module allowed

**I tried the following:**

*1. Extending the controller with XClasses & adding a new method cleanupAction*

Problems with that:

- cleanupAction is not allowed
- Action would have to be added to ext_tables.php of the original module. But this is not allowed.

*2. An own backend module:*

Problem with that:

An entry in main nav in backend is generated, which is not desired and not needed.

Do you have any ideas how to tackle the problem? **I only want to have an action, which can be called in the backend, without having a main-nav entry.**
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set up your own extension, containing a controller, some typoscript setup and a template.

The typoscript is used to change the template of the original backend module to your own version of the template:
module.tx_originalextension.view.templateRootPath = EXT:my_new_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/

Copy all templates from the original extension to your new extension. Add the new "delete all" button where you need it and link it with your new extension controller -> deleteAllAction. Of course, you need to implement the deleteAllAction in your controller.

In your controller, inject the original repository from the original extension, and use it to delete the data.

Remember to check the links in the copied templates. They need to point to the original extension, so add "extensionName" to any f:link.action calls expect the new "deleteAll" link.